# Here Satellite Map WMS or WMTS service

Tags: openlayers, here-api, qgis, wms

Here map has WMS or WMTS services for satellite map?
**Edit:** I want to get getCapabilities with WMS and WMTS like Oracle's mapviewer

When I searched on google, I found only the service below. I need an XML output service, but this service returns png

https://1.aerial.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/5/15/12/256/png8?app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ

Thank you for responses

Comment: You are unlikely to find any.  Satellite imagery is a raster format, XML is used for vector data.

Comment: both WMS and WMTS return images

Comment: @IanTurton i want to get capabilities from wms or wmts and Oracle provides this with mapviewer wms and wmts as XML format

Comment: In that case you need to make clear that you want a capabilities document in the question. AFAIK here.com don't provide a WMS or WMTS endpoint

Comment: If you need a public satellite imagery service with WMTS capabilities you could try Mapbox
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/wmts?access_token=.....  (it's a simple XYZ layer but has a WMTS capabilities url for compatibility with other services)

Comment: Thank you Mike but i have HERE's app_code

Answer (score 0):

HERE only offer rasterised version of satellite and don’t support WMS or WTMS services for satellite map. Arial does not return XML output, it only returns PNG format with meta data and this meta data includes some information on what you can see on the image such as street names for example.